# Thread safe IQueryable extension method

Tags: c#, multithreading, methods, iqueryable

I want to create an generic extension method that will receive IQueryable and 
will preform an operation(like getting top ten elements) on a separate thread/task in a way that will be thread safe.

can someone please give me an code example of the right way to do that

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
    public static List<T> GetTopN<T>(IQueryable<T> inData, int n)
    {
        List<T> outData = new List<T>(n);

        lock (inData)
        {
            int i = 0;
            foreach (T t in inData)
            {
                if (i >= n)
                {
                    return outData;
                }

                i++;

                outData.Add(t);
            }
        }

        return outData;
    }
```